# Google Collaborative Inbox mirgration

Tags: python, .net, google-apps, google-groups-api, google-groups-migration

Has any one shared or published any code for doing a email migration for Google groups / Google's Collaborative Inbox.

Looking at moving from Exchange but need a method to move a mailbox in to Google's Collaborative Inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Google's tool, [Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Exchange (GAMME)](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration) supports migration of an Exchange public folder to a Google Group but not from an Exchange user mailbox to a Google Group. For the latter, you can utilize [Cloud Solution's CloudMigrator](http://www.cloudsolutions.co.uk/resources/migration-tool/) tool.

Both of these products utilize Google's openly documented [Groups Migration API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/).